# ¿Tiene algún efecto "use strict" fuera de una clase javascript?

Tags: javascript

`'use strict';` se puede incluir al comiendo de un fichero de javascript. Tiene efecto si el fichero sólo contiene una clase, es decir dentro del cuerpo de la misma, p.e., ¿con algo así?

```
'use strict';

class Foo 
{
    // ¿está éste código en modo estricto?
}
```

La [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#invocar_el_modo_estricto) indica que tiene efecto en todo el script o en funciones, pero no dentro de un bloque delimitado por llaves:

> El modo estricto se aplica a un script completo o a funciones
> individuales. No se aplica a bloques entre corchetes {}; intentar
> aplicarlo en tales contextos no hace nada.

En este sentido, hay ejemplos en que se declara *uso estricto* dentro de funciones, de ahí surge mi duda ya que no hay ejemplos o explicaciones sobre clases en la documentación. No se si la declaración a nivel de documento afecta al código encerrado dentro de una clase y ya puestos al de una función...

Comment: ***Tiene algun efecto si el fichero sólo contiene una clase*** ¿Efecto de que tipo? ¿Has consultado lo que dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) sobre el modo estricto?

Answer (score 0):

#### Respuesta empírica

Para aclararlo podemos hacer algunas pruebas basándonos en los ejemplos del punto [Cambios en modo estricto / Convertir equivocaciones en errores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#convertir_equivocaciones_en_errores)
 de la documentación.

Este es el tercer ejemplo:

```
'use strict';
delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
```

Para este ejemplo, el error obtenido será:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property 'prototype' of function
> Object() { [native code] }

Si **se aplica el modo estricto a nivel de documento** y añadimos el error **dentro de una función veremos que se aplica el modo estricto**:

```
'use strict';
function test() // void
{
    delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
}
test();
```

También podemos comprobar que **el modo estricto a nivel de documento *se aplica dentro de una clase***:

```
'use strict';
class Foo // class
{
    constructor() // constructor
    {
        delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
    }
}
new Foo();
```

#### Aclaraciones finales

Usar modo estricto a nivel de documento aplica a todo el código del documento incluidos el interior de funciones y clases*.

El modo estricto puede usarse solo en el interior de funciones concretas, para lo que se declara en su cuerpo (interior) al inicio del mismo.

**Ejemplo de *modo estricto limitado al interior de una función*:**

```
function noStrict() // void
{
    delete Object.prototype; // NO lanza nada
}
function strict() // void
{
    'use strict';
    delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
}

noStrict();
strict();
```

**El modo estricto aplica en el interior de una clase aunque este modo no se declare en el documento ni en la clase**.
En este sentido los siguientes dos ejemplos tiene idéntico resultado (no se declaro modo estricto a nivel de documento):

```
class NoStrictClass // class
{
    constructor() // constructor
    {
        delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
    }
}
new NoStrictClass();


class StrictClass // class
{
    'use strict';

    constructor() // constructor
    {
        delete Object.prototype; // lanza un TypeError
    }
}
new StrictClass();
```

##### Luego **Sí, el modo estricto aplica dentro del cuerpo de una clase en JavaScript** (aunque este modo no se declare ni en el documento ni en el cuerpo de la clase).

***NOTA:** puede haber cambios en como los diferentes navegadores aplican el modo estricto (pruebas con Chromium 95.0.4 en Ubuntu)*.